# python problems in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python, python3

When i run the command,

```
sudo update-alternatives  --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.7
```

some applications in Ubuntu 18.04 don't work like launching terminal from shortcut key or from dock. But when I again switch to Python3.6, it starts functioning again. I also work with Python 3, but all package are installed in Python 3.6. Is there any way that all Python 3 packages should be installed on all Python 3 version in Ubuntu?

when i work with Python 3.6 in Ubuntu terminal all packages work, but with Python 3.7 none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

The python interpretter that comes bundled with Ubuntu is built upon by tools that can potentially require the specific version chosen by the distro maintainers. As a result, manually changing the bundled python version is usually a bad idea.

If you want to use a different version of python than the bundled one, then look at a Python version manager. I recommend pyenv, it's fairly easy to use and let's you install as many parallel python interpretters as you want.

Comment: can you please guide through steps to activate pyenv. i have successfully installed on ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: @AjayKhrolia pyenv has some very helpful and very useful documentation that answers your question. Have you read through it yet?